# Как запросить доступ к конкретному файлу через SAF, зная только его реальный путь

Tags: android

В базе и преференсах хранятся пути к файлам.
Нужно обновить приложение, соответственно повысить targetSDK, соответственно перевести на Document API.

**Вопрос**: как теперь получить доступ к этим файлам?

Я понимаю что нужно запросить их через SAF, и чтобы юзер не искал их по всем
провайдерам можно указать стартовый uri:

```java
intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, Uri.parse(startPath));
```

Но я не нашёл в API никакой возможности получить document uri из файла или файлового пути.

Попытка найти их через `MediaStore` не увенчалась успехом - как я понял они не попадают в её базу из-за маркера `.nomedia`.
Провайдер, выдающий файлы, не даёт информации по файлам, к которым не получен доступ.
Видится только одно решение - запрашивать доступ к корням томов, делать траверс папок и сравнивать имена и пути.
Но какой тогда вообще смысл этих нововведений, если разработчики будут запрашивать доступ ко всем файлам, чтобы найти один - пользователи будут его давать, потому что иначе приложение откажется работать, и вся хвалёная безопасность останется там же, где и была...

Comment: Как вариант: просить пользователя, чтобы он их выбрал через Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT с множественным выбором и потом запрашивать разрешения

Comment: @Style-7, поясню - есть список избранного, в нём есть пути к файлам (которые юзер выбирал через встроенный в приложение проводник), по клику на файл я должен его открыть, а не заставить юзера искать по всем провайдерам неизвестно что и неизвестно где. Но на Android 11 я не могу сделать так: `DocumentFile.fromFile(...)` - это не работает, а content-uri у меня нет и я не представляю как его сотворить из обычного пути к файлу.

Comment: мне интересно, а если просто пытаться читать файлы зная путь без разрешений будет ли вылетать Security Exception? Нашли решение?

Comment: Не на чем тестировать. В доках вроде обещается что читать можно с привилегией `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, но мне надо их ещё и редактировать.