# Content uri и относительные пути

Tags: android

Приложение на основе `WebView` для просмотра локальных html-станиц, которые естественно содержат относительные ссылки на файлы ресурсов и других страниц.
На Android 4.2.2 всё работало из коробки: открываем любой html хоть в самописном, хоть в стоковом проводнике всё остальное подхватывается само собой.
Теперь нужно обновить аппу на Android 10+: из стока прилетает `content:bla-bla` с правом чтения только одного прилетевшего файла.
Как получить остальное?

Comment: 2 серия https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1359649/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-saf-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82#comment2421965_1359649 ?

Comment: @Style-7, там несколько о другом. У меня много претензий к доступу в ФС, которые в других ОС решаются в пару строк и минут работы, а тут наворотили хрен знает что и походу сами не знают как с этим работать, потому что в примерах и гайдах нет ничего толкового, кроме как запросить выбор неизвестно чего у юзера

Comment: А если это локальное хранилище попросить перенести пользователя в getExternalFilesDir(), будет работать тогда?

Comment: Работать-то будет, но какой юзер захочет это делать - каждому подобному приложению переносить файлы в его директорию, чтобы потом в этом приложении их открыть. И опять-таки файл нужно будет открывать из самого приложения, а не проводника.

Answer (score 0):

Я пришёл к выводу, что ловить интенты от сторонних приложений не имеет смысла.
Андроид не предъявляет абсолютно никаких требований ни к провайдерам, ни к содержимому uri и не гарантирует что по этому uri можно вообще что-то получить.
В лучшем случае я смогу показать голую нераскрашенную html с мёртвыми ссылками.

Запрашивать выбор html через SAF не имеет смысла по причине того, что DocumentProvider не даёт доступ к содержимому и информации файлов, к которым приложение не имеет доступа, а доступ получить никак нельзя - только запросить выбор и не факт, что пользователь выберет то что нужно и вообще захочет это делать на каждый требуемый файл. Результат тот же: голый текст одной страницы.

Возможен только один вариант: предоставить выбор html через самописный проводник, встроенный в приложение. Для поддержки Андроид 11 придётся написать его поверх Document-API и перед началом работы просить юзера выбрать через SAF папку, в рамках которой будет возможна навигация.

В общем приложение получится очень "удобным" - лично я бы такое себе не поставил, если бы не знал как это всё устроено.